# How to make a UIBarButtonItem add a new NSDate object into an NSDictionary

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsmutabledictionary

I'm currently trying to set up an `NSMutableDictionary` with date objects that when added will be a unique date with an automatically added key.

Example:

```
object:20-04-2014 withKey:datekey1;
object:21-04-2014 withKey:datekey2;
```

I want save an `NSDate` as an object and a key which will be explained below:

For example an `NSDate` object is added to the dictionary

> 20-04-2014 //for example

This object needs to be given the key of 'key = total NSMutableDictionary keys +1'

An example of how this should now look within the `NSMutableDictionary`

```
withObject:"20-04-2014" forKey:"key1"
```

When the `UIBarButtonItem` is pressed again and a different date is selected, for example the following day:

> 21-04-2014 // new NSDate object to be added as an object to the
>   dictionary..

When giving the 2nd `NSDate` object a key it should automatically be considered that there is already 1 entry and to give a key value of key=totalkeys+1

The following should now be in `NSMutableDictionary`

```
withObject:"20-04-2014" forKey:"key1"
withObject:"21-04-2014" forKey:"key2"
```

ect ect. The number of entries should have the ability to be unlimited.

How is this done?

Regards.

Comment: Where are you blocked exactly? What's your issue, since your seem to have to decompose all the steps. Which one annoy you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method invoked when you tap the button:

```
NSString *k = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"key%d", _dictionary.count+1];
[_dictionary setObject:date forKey:k];
```